# Asp.NET Web application: run a method every x hours (long term)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

Is it possible to automate a method to run every x minutes/hours within a web application (server side of course)?

Simplified code:

```
public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The case: Each task has a deadline, I want to generate a **mail** if the deadline is approaching.

There are some answers, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019433/calling-method-on-every-x-minutes) with *System.Threading* or embed the functionality into a constructor. But how can I make sure, it will work for months without to be called?

Thank you!

Comment: a windows service?

Comment: Create a windows service separate to your web app.

Comment: Use a window service. IIS does not guarantee that a worker process is running in the absence of requests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589682/windows-service-that-will-run-every-hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite tool for this is [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). It lets you schedule tasks, your task would look like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => CheckIfDeadlineIsApproaching(), Cron.Hourly);
```

Unlike the suggestions in the comments this doesn't require a Windows Service either, which makes this solution much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should put scheduler in application start. I think `Global.asax.cs` file

Comment: Who vote me down, you can look at any lib dos to make sure to run any persistent process, it should be placed in application start in web app.